# ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE when following updated Build First Network tutorial

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

It looks like the updated "Build Your First Network" tutorial is using new endorsement policies with organisation's `"peers"` instead of `"members"`, in example: `"OR ('Org0MSP.peer','Org1MSP.peer')"`. This doesn't seems to work well with `invoke` transaction issued from CLI later on, as it can't pass validation stage with `ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE` error.
Problem was fixed once changed endorsement policy back to `"OR ('Org0MSP.member','Org1MSP.member')"`. Not sure whether the problem is in whether `cryptoconfig` is not supporting new identity types or somewhere else?

Comment: Hey Nikolay, Thanks for catching the bug. I believe you're referring to [this section](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html#install-instantiate-chaincode) of the documentation. While the text content says `-P "OR ('Org0MSP.peer','Org1MSP.peer')"` the golang command provided below that instead uses `-P "OR ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"` which is correct.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for clarifications, Sudheesh!